# Geothermal dog bowl heater/cooler

Tags: plumbing

I live near Denver, where we have winters cold enough to freeze an outdoor dog bowl, and summers hot enough to make the water warm (not hot enough to be a problem, but cold water always tastes better on a hot day).

My thought is to rent an auger and dig a 10-12" diameter hole down 6-8 feet, then run a loop of PEX down to the bottom. The loop would be either just straight down and back up (easy) or a sort of helix (more surface area). Then I'd fill the dirt back in, put a small pump in the line, and do some sort of heatsink against a metal dog bowl.

Come winter, the goal is to keep the water warm enough not to freeze. Come summer, cooler than it would be just sitting out.

Think it's feasible? Would a 6-8' deep hole give enough heat transfer?

Comment: Just a couple thoughts... Use copper pipe, instead of PEX. The copper will allow heat to move to/from the transfer medium better.  Secondly, use a refrigerant in the coil instead of water.  You'll want a coil of pipe in the bottom of the hole, and a coil around the metal drinking dish. You'll want to insulate the above ground coil, so that it moves heat to/from the water, not the surrounding air.

Comment: Am I the only one thinking that if its that cold or hot outside maybe the dog should come in? Otherwise it may be more efficient due to the cost of running a pump (and somehow refilling the water and keeping the feed from freezing) that you could just buy a heated water dish?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of effort and money to solve a solved problem. An off the shelf, 25W heated dog bowl ($20) will use around $8 of electricity per year if it runs 12 hours/day (it's thermostaticallly controlled so it won't be using power 100% of the time) for 180 days a year. You'll have to keep the pump running pretty much 24x7 in freezing weather to keep the water from freezing in the pipe so even if it uses less power than the heater, it may run longer, which reduces any energy savings.

Answer (score 1):

It's an intriguing proposition, but no. You wouldn't move enough heat with a small loop like that. Geothermal systems move a very large volume of water to extract a relatively small energy differential.

Comment: A Geothermal Heat Pump also uses a compressor and change-of-state to transfer heat. Which makes them extremely efficient.

Comment: Right, but they still depend on volume. We don't have phase-change or volume in this scenario.

Comment: True. I think the farmers use a circulation pump to keep water troughs from freezing but they may add a heater element to that too.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting concept. You may have to add a coil of copper at the bottom of your hole to get the desired coupling and heat transfer. Pex is not very good at heat transfer. You may also want to insulate the Pex until it passes into the ground. (Have you considered heat tape wrapped around a metal dish for the winter?)

Just keeping the water moving in the winter may keep it from freezing as long as the temperature doesn't drop too low. Eventually you may draw enough heat from the earth that it will lose its effectiveness.

Without doing some actual calculations with volume of water and difference in temperature you will just be experimenting but it sounds like a fun project anyway.

Good Luck!